# Midnight Commander - editor in hex mode

Tags: linux, mc

I can't find a way to toggle mc internal editor in hex mode. [Here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue23/wkndmech_dec97/mc_article.html) it says to use F4 however it suggest to replace. How to do it?

Comment: Try [`hte`](http://hte.sourceforge.net/) for an actual hex *editor*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open file with <kbd>F3</kbd>.
Hex view - <kbd>F4</kbd>.
Start edit - <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>F4</kbd> toggles hex mode in the Midnight Commander **viewer** (accessed using <kbd>F3</kbd>), not in the editor. Once in hex mode in the viewer, <kbd>F2</kbd> allows you to make changes to the file being viewed.

As you discovered, <kbd>F4</kbd> in the editor starts a search.